# Intuition for metric space completion

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Is this intuition for the completion of an arbitrary metric space (X,$\rho$) correct? I am trying to understand Royden's argument in his Real Analysis book.

Construct $\tilde X$ as union of two parts: X $\bigcup$ (space of limit points $\bar X$); where X is dense in $\tilde X$.

The the metric of $\tilde X$ is defined in the following way:

1. if u, v $\in X$, then $\tilde \rho (u, v) = \rho (u, v)$ which is Cauchy in $\Bbb R$ so converges.
2. if u, v $\in \bar X$ (space of limit points), then $\tilde \rho (u, v)$ = lim $\rho (u, v)$.
3. if u $\in X$ and v $\in \bar X$, then since $\bar X$ is complete, I can take any sequence from $\bar X$ to converge to an element u $\in X$. So I need a mapping of the $\bar X$ sequence and the X sequence onto the same space, say $\hat X$.

Now $\hat X$ needs to be a quotient space so that it has a well-defined metric $\hat \rho ([u], [v]) = \rho^*$,  where [.] is equivalence classes for which$\rho^* (x_n, y_n)$ = 0 and $\rho^*$ = lim$\rho (x_n, y_n)$.

Does this make sense?

Comment: The completion of a metric space is basically the construction of a space of limit points. As I understand your description, you assume that such an object exists from the beginning?